# Volume integral $\int_V y \frac{dy}{dt} + z\frac{dz}{dt} dV$

Tags: integration

How do I solve

$$\int_V y \frac{dy}{dt} + z\frac{dz}{dt} dV$$

Where $V$ is the volume of a hollow sphere.

Usually I would use spherical coordinates, but I don't know how to express $\frac{dy}{dt} $ and $\frac{dz}{dt}$ in spherical coordinates.

EDIT: The actual problem is to calculate the angular momentum of a rotating hollow sphere with constant density.
To do this, one needs to calculate $ \rho \int_V \vec r \times (\vec w \times \frac{d\vec r}{dt} )$. Using $bac-cab$-rule, I receive my initial form.

Comment: How do $x$ and $z$ depend on $t$?

Comment: note my edit ...

Comment: For people that know more physics this is probably obvious, but what are $r$ and $w$?  $\rho$ is a constant?

Comment: I'm not sure the answer to my previous question matters much actually.  You just need to use that $z=r\cos \phi$ and $y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$ and then use the chain rule.

Comment: @Callus $\vec r$ is the position vector of the volume element $dV$. $\vec w$ is the angular frequency. Both $w$ and $\rho$ are constant.

Comment: Are you certain that you have the physics correct?  $\vec L=\vec r \times \vec p$ and $\vec p=(\rho dS) \vec v=(\rho dS) (\vec \omega \times \vec r$, does it not?

Comment: yes, this is given in the initial task

Comment: Your integral looks like it has the wrong units. Angular momentum is in $\text{kg}\cdot \text{m}^2/\text{s}$ but that expression $\text{kg}\cdot \text{m}^2/\text{s}^2$.

Comment: Why? $\frac{kg}{m}$ from $\rho$ , $m$ from $y$ and $z$, $m/s$ from $\frac{dy}{dt}$ and $m^3$ from dV. The product of all this equals $\frac{kgm^2}{s} $

Comment: The angular velocity $w$ has units of $s^{-1}$.